# how can I to put the value of temp at the end of 3-Dimension list? am I right?

Tags: python, list, numpy

[image: 1]

`currentStep` shape is (1, 20, 1)

like in this picture, I want to insert temp value in `currentStep` last position and remove first position (where 20 corresponding part)

how can I'm to put the value of temp at the end of the `currentStep`

To express... `[:, I want to put temp value in end of here, and remove first position :]`

I tried

```
currentStep = currentStep[:,1:,:]
currentStep[:,-1:,:] = temp
```

this code is remove last element I want insert temp element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945410/python-numpy-equivalent-of-list-pop), you could use a combination of [np.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) and [np.append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

```
In [20]: inner = [[i] for i in range(20)]

In [21]: arr = np.array([inner])

In [22]: arr.shape
Out[22]: (1, 20, 1)

In [23]: arr = np.delete(arr, 0, 1)

In [24]: arr.shape
Out[24]: (1, 19, 1)

In [61]: np.append(arr[0], [[12]],axis=0)
Out[61]:array([[ 1],[ 2], [ 3], [ 4], [ 5], [ 6], [ 7], [ 8], [ 9],
               [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [12]])
```

To put it at the beginning use [numpy.insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
np.insert(arr2, 0, 12,1)
```

Comment: It's what I wanted but, I want 12 to last position `np.insert(currentStep, -1, 12, 1)` doesn't work....
I tried Like this  https://imgur.com/6llKlgZ  12 doesn't go last position

Comment: Updated to answer your actual questions. Note that I used axis as a keyword argument in append, I could not get `np.append(arr[0], [[12]], 0)` to work.