# Change numpy array element position in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Supposed that I have an array like matrix using numpy like this.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

I want to change the [13, 14, 15, 16] into the first position so it will become something like this

```
array([[ 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4 ],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8 ],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ],
       [ 17, 18, 19, 20])
```

how can I do it? thanks

Comment: This might be close to what you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497203/5171751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.delete` and `np.concatenate`:

```
b = np.concatenate([a[[-2]], np.delete(a, -2, axis=0)])
print(b)

# Output
[[13 14 15 16]
 [ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [17 18 19 20]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can re-arrange the array with the row indices:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]])

b = a[[3,0,1,2,4],:]

print(b)
```

The output is:

```
[[13 14 15 16]
 [ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [17 18 19 20]]
```